# How should I model this?

Tags: modeling

I am finding it hard to model this curved neck of the guitar since it is carved from a single piece of wood and am unable to keep a nice and clean topology. It would be great if someone could help me regarding this.
Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good place to use the power of the Bridge Edge Loop tool

[image]

(left to right)

- Starting with a geometry like this:
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > Bridge Edge Loop the curved sections of profile, with surface interpolation -  adjust the number of cuts and smoothness to your liking.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> cut corresponding edge loops in the base and back, and if you're picky like me, <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> the new loops with Snap (vertex, active) so they're straight to the loops in the curved section.  Again, Bridge Edge Loops to form the sides. Now's the time to tweak the curvatures if you want to, using <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to slide edges, loops,  or vertices. Cut in some extra loops to keep the face density reasonably even, close to the curved section.
- Assign a Bevel modifier with 2 segments to the edges you want to remain sharper (Here I did it by weight) .. and a Subdivision Surface modifier.

Apart from the pair of poles at the corner, the topology is still in unbroken quad loops, making it relatively quick to adjust, if you need to.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of trying to model the curves manually, you could instead let the subsurf modifier do most of the heavy lifting for you.

An example of this might be something like:

[image]
[image]

Comment: ..apologies for almost repeating your answer.. I just wanted to include the steps.

Comment: No worries mate, I could've probably spent a little more time preparing a more complete answer like what you did. I had the impression the op was not a beginer hence the straightforward answer.

Answer (score 1):

What do you think about this topology (I'm not sure to see the same thing than you, though)?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to make sketches first. It is a good help to figure out complex meshes.

I made this one and I hope it is good enough to help you.

[image]

Comment: Actually I would like to avoid tris and ngons to keep my topology as clean as possible. Thanks for the sketch though.

Answer (score -2):

id try using an inset and pull the face out. you can use subsurf to smooth things out whenyou finish the model or make it its own separate obj and subsurf now