# How to proper model Toilet as in example

Tags: modeling

I'm quite new to Blender, but already got some experience modelling.
I'm trying to model a Toilet as the one shown in the photo attached, but i'm having issues to achieve the same shapes below the main vase, I've circled the area on the image to let you better understand what i'm talking about.
Are you able to describe the step by step model instructions that will help me to achieve the final results?

[image]
Thank you so much for any help you'll provide.

Cristiano

Comment: Hello and  welcome to Blender.SE :). Please share images of your current progress, and specify where exactly you're stuck. Without that, it's hard to help you :).

Comment: @Merlin if you believe that to be the case, you can edit or vote to close the question in addition to the DV.   Modelling with good topo only looks easy. As an example of well received q but  [Not the same shape](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/122038/how-should-i-model-this)

Answer (score -1):

Here’s my best crack at it. I used Curves to create edge loops which I then bridged, subdivided, creased as needed, and mirrored.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xjdiLHzDEVY&feature=youtu.be

I would highly recommend watching a car modeling tutorial (or better yet, invest in a true hard-surface modeling course) to understand approaching difficult shapes like these which you’ll encounter many times in the future.

Good luck,

John

Comment: Hi John! I think your walkthrough is very cool! In general, though, we tend to keep most of the information that is useful to answer a question *within* this site, and use external links only for further reference. I believe you could provide a much nicer and accessible answer by expanding a bit the *«I used Curves to create edge loops which I then bridged, subdivided, creased as needed, and mirrored»* part, using bullet points and screenshots (for instance, taking screenshots of the 3D viewport -- no need for the entire screen -- from the video itself)